# How to combine ASP.NET skin file and DevExpress theme assembly?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

Can you combine ASP.NET skin file and DevExpress theme assembly?

I am currently testing DevExpress components for web development. My goal is to use skin files to change some properties across multiple components in a web application. For example, I want to set PageSize property for ASPxGridView. What I ultimately want to achieve is to have some predefined theme ie. Metropolis and then change some minor attributes in skin file.
As far as I could gather there are two ways apply a theme:

1. Apply a theme with ASP.NET mechanism. To do that you should create a folder structure with necessary files

> ```
> App_Themes 
>    Metropolis
>        Controls.Skin
>        Metropolis.css
>        … images …
> ```

The downside is that this is not recommended devxpress approach and I have to maintain all the theme files. And all I want to change is a single setting in skin file

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dx" Namespace="DevExpress.Data" assembly="DevExpress.Data.v14.1, Version=14.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dx" Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v14.1, Version=14.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" %>
<dx:ASPxGridView runat="server" >
    <SettingsPager PageSize="20">
    </SettingsPager>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

2. Appy a theme wih DevExpress Mechanism 
   Create a new theme assembly and deploy it to web app.
   On uses the following setting in web.config

> ```
> <devExpress>
>     <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="Metropolis" />
> </devExpress>
> ```

The down side is that to change a single setting (pageSize) one has to go through a whole procedure to create a custom assembly. This takes time and unnecessary work. Even to open a theme in devexpress ASPxThemeBuilder tool takes ages. To put it short… stupid. Other downside is that applied changes are lost in the whole mass. One does not have an overview what was changed and what not. Also very bad.

I was wondering if there is a third way which is hinted in devexpess documentation. But their docs are a lot of words and very little said. Namely my idea si to use built in theme assembly and then combine it with a simple skin file where I would define only properties that I need to modify. Yet, devexpress docs do not provide more information on that topic.
Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the [ASP.NET mechanism](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11725), specify the Theme via the corresponding property (not via the DevExpress section):

```
<system.web>
    <pages theme="Metropolis" />
     ...
</system.web>

<devExpress>
    <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="" />
</devExpress>
```

> I was wondering if there is a third way which is hinted in devexpess documentation.

Check this topic: [Appearance Customization - Theming](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11689)

Comment: This answer gave me enough to solve the issue. Upvoted and accepted. I have edited the answer to include complete solution.